# Remove tags from html not getting removed

Tags: php

Am I doing something wrong here? I am trying to remove all the tags that are of one of the following: `style, script, pre, code`.

When I do a dump on the end result, the items that are in that block are still there.

```
$removes = $xpath->query('//style | //script | //pre | //code');

if($removes instanceof DOMNodeList){
    foreach($removes as $removable){
        if($removable instanceof DOMElement){
            $removable->parentNode->removeChild($removable);
        }
    }
}

$content = $this->document->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;

var_dump($content);
```

Comment: Do you have some example HTML to try this on?

Comment: I was using this: view-source:http://phpsnips.com/129/Dynamic-Image-Uploading-::-Automatic-Create-File-Uploading-Field#.VhbFr_lVhBc

Comment: above source link is unclear.... there is not any pre tag.... Be specific

Comment: There are code tags and script tags though. If the code above is correct the pre tags will get caught along with those tags.

Comment: Well have you checked if your xpath query actually matches any elements …?

Comment: @CBroe `var_dump($removes->length)` returns `int(30)`

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, in isolation, works fine. What is likely happening is you're working within a namespace and so your `instanceof` checks should use the fully-qualified names `\DOMNodeList` and `\DOMElement` (note the leading backslashes.)

Comment: I have: `use DOMDocument;
use DOMElement;
use DOMXPath;`

Comment: Wonder why it didn't throw an error or warning or notice or anything... Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: `instanceof` doesn’t throw any errors if the class is not known. You can have `$x instanceof Foo` without having a class `Foo` anywhere in your code, that will just silently return false.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this solution is interesting for you:

```
function strip_selected_tags($text, $tags = array())
{
  foreach ($tags as $tag){
    if(preg_match_all('/<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*)<\/'.$tag.'>/iU', $text, $found)){
      $text = str_replace($found[0],$found[1],$text);
    }
  }

  return $text;
}

$tags = array( 'style', 'script', 'pre', 'code');
echo strip_selected_tags($text,$tags);
```

Comment: so many syntax errors. and using regular expressions to parse HTML is not a good idea